# TypeError: Cannot add module namespace property '_nuxtConfigFile' to nuxt.config.js with NUXT 2.4.5

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am upgrading to Nuxt 2.4.5 and getting below error
`TypeError: Cannot add module namespace property '_nuxtConfigFile' to nuxt.config.js`

Comment: just got the same error :)

Comment: which version I'm trying to upgrade nuxt 2.3.4 -> nuxt 2.4.5

Comment: i'm upgrading from 2.2.* to 2.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its caused by updated esm dependency. You are most likely mixing commonjs and es6 in your nuxt.config. E.g. use both require and import, or import and module.exports.

To fix it use only import and export default without require

Here issue in esm repo -> https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/773 and it was already fixed, should be working in next esm release e.g. 3.2.23 and later

Comment: Thanks, it's work :) 2 things to do:
• require -> import
• module.export -> export default

Comment: Getting this `WARNING: We noticed you're using the useBuiltIns option without declaring a core-js version. Currently, we assume version 2.x when no version is passed. Since this default version will likely change in future versions of Babel, we recommend explicitly setting the core-js version you are using via the corejs option.You should also be sure that the version you pass to the corejs option matches the version specified in your package.json's dependencies section. If it doesn't, you need to run one of the following commands:npm install --save core-js@2    npm install --save core-js@3`

Comment: @Aldarund using nuxt@2.4.5 getting above warning message for `core-js`

Comment: @HardikShah its totally different thing and nowhere near related to this SO question

Comment: @Aldarund Yes, I know. Just if you have also face same or any solution. do you have any solution?!

Answer (score 7):

Replace module.exports = {} from ***nuxt.config.js*** to export default { }

Comment: I am still mixing both import and require, but the `export default {}` was enough to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a faulty dependency issue, but I wasn't able to figure out which dep. is responsible.
I had the same issue and was unable to solve it with the following:

- reset npm cache
- delete node_modules folder
- delete package-lock.json
- restart machine
- update npm
- downgrade recent npm updates
- cloning the repo again
- installed/used yarn instead

then I reinstalled modules using yarn with an older yarn.lock and everything was working fine again, as it was earlier today. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also switching nuxt version from 2.4.5 to 2.5.1 and vice versa didn't make a difference

Comment: caused by esm update. dont mix es6 and commonjs in nuxt.config

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue yesterday. My project was built with NuxtJs 2.4.5. This is a sudden problem because the same code was deployed successfully the day before yesterday.


After I deleted node_moules folder, package-lock.json file and npm cache, the issue still cannot be solved.


I am not sure if there is a problem in the third-party dependency package that the Nuxt framework depends on.


Finally, I found a historical version project(Nuxtjs 2.2) that can work. Used its package.json and package-lock.json file, then replaced the files in my current project, after deleted node_modules folder and "npm install" again, it works(But Nuxt version was downgraded to 2.2 ).

Comment: caused by esm update. dont mix es6 and commonjs in nuxt.config